# IS There any Plugin for Chrome in Selenium to find xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My Application is not compatible with Firefox hence i have to Opt for Chrome. Is there any Plugin to find xpath quickly for Chrome Browser just like firebug for Firefox ??

Apart from xpath Helper and xpath Finder any other Plugin would be appreciated

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native chrome console tool works well!
Just click right mouse button on the element you want to find, then click "Inspect element". After it you'll see code of this element.
Click right mouse button on the code and you'll be able to copy xPath and CssPath as well.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/86tx5i